# How to access request scoped bean in controller?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to understand the request scoped beans. Suppose I have a controller and I have a request scoped bean instantiated using spring config xml

```
<bean id="loginAction" class="com.foo.LoginAction" scope="request"/>
```

Do I need to add it as a dependency in controller to access it or I can access it directly from request object doing request.getAttribute("loginAction")

I just wanted to know how would I access this request scoped bean.

Thanks.

Comment: "Do I need to add it as a dependency in controller to access it or I can access it directly from request object doing request.getAttribute("loginAction")" Surely you could have spared ten minutes to actually try this for yourself before asking?

Comment: you have to use `aop:scoped-proxy` or `@ScopedProxy` check this [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) from spring refrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@Autowired` annotation for this case.

```
@Autowired
private LoginAction loginAction;
```

and then add package for this bean as candidate for autowiring:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo"></context:component-scan>
```

and don't forget to mark this class as `@Component` or `@Service`.

Comment: I understabd what you say and I agree with the idea, but why would  the name of the bean have to change? I see no problem in using LoginAction for autowiring.

Comment: @danny.lesnik I believe you mean to say use LoginAction instead of RequestScopeBean :-)

Comment: Sure. I just wrote this code out of my mind,I changed it according to your question, I just wanted to show the principle of bean autowiring and used my custom name :)

Comment: Well, if his Controller is singleton-scoped, then your @Autowire/@Inject won't work (which instance of LoginAction should be autowired/injected on Controller creation when application starts?).
It can be done either making LoginAction scoped-proxy (which I don't like), or autowiring/injecting a Provider<LoginAction> (which I use).